# Matrix norm question, normal matrices

Tags: matrices

Let $A^*$ denote the complex conjugate transpose of a matrix $A$. In the Euclidean norm (operator norm), if
$$\|A^*A+AA^*\|=2\,\|A^*A\|$$
prove/disprove that $A$ is normal.

Comment: What matrix norm are you using? The operator norm is **not** the Euclidean norm, but a norm *induced by* the Euclidean norm. If we view $M_n(\mathbb C)$ as $\mathbb C^{n^2}$, the Euclidean norm is the Frobenius norm. $A$ is indeed normal if the Frobenius norm is used in the given condition, but not necessarily normal if the operator norm is used.

Comment: Of course you are correct. I found some articles saying the Euclidean norm (meaning the operator norm), hence thought it was well-established. But, since you are the second person today, I must reconsider my view and be more careful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the matrix
$$ A= \begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0\\ 1 & 0 &0\\ 0 &0& 10\end{pmatrix}$$
then
$$AA^* = \begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0\\ 0 & 1 &0\\ 0 &0& 100\end{pmatrix},A^*A \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0 & 0 &0\\ 0 &0& 100\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{ and }\quad A^*A +AA^*=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0 & 1 &0\\ 0 &0& 200\end{pmatrix}. $$
So, $A^*A$ has $100$ as maximum eigenvalue and $A^*A+AA^*$ has $200$ as maximum eigenvalue. Since these are nonnegative symmetric matrices (namely $A^*A$ and $A^*A+AA^*$), we have $\|A^*A+AA^*\| = 200$ and $\|A^*A\|=100$ however $A$ is not normal.